# PHP: Whois via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am extremely bad at AJAX (actually, I just started to learn it).

So, I write whois service on PHP and I want to make it to output the result via AJAX-request.

All I have at the moment is:

my PHP code:

```
$domain = $_POST['domain'];
$whois = new Whois();
header("content-type:application/json");
$res = $whois->getWhois($domain); // Calls the Whois-query function;

echo json_encode($res);
```

my JS code:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    var domain = $('#value').val();
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/whois.php',
    type: "post",
    data: {'domain': domain, 'action': 'whois'},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(json) {
        $('#whoisResult').html('<h2>Whois Query result for ' + domain + '</h2>');
        $('#whoisContent').html(json.html);
    },

    error: function(xhr, status) {
        $('#whoisResult').html('<h2>Sorry, an error occured. Try again later, please!</h2>')
    }
});
```

As HTML I have an input: `<input type="text" id="value">` and the submit button.

I searched for the script examples and tried to make something similar, but it does not work at all...

P.S. Guess you won't hit this question a negative rating :)

P.P.S: As requested, this is my response from PHP:

```
{"domain":"exp.cm","whois":"[Domain]\nDomain: exp.cm\nStatus: active\nChanged: 2014-02-25T12:22:00.957819+02:00\n\n[Holder]\nType: Legal person\nName: Name, Surname\nEmail: email@example.com\nPhone: Phone here\nAddress: Address goes here\nSome other info\n\nUpdated: 2014-03-18T18:12:35.717462+00:00\n"}
```

Comment: I don't see you outputting anything in your PHP code...

Comment: Additionally, perhaps you meant to do `echo json_encode($res);` ?

Comment: Yeah, sure, I have this string. Just forgot to add to the question, sorry :)

Comment: Can you provide an example output of the JSON? Also, your `$.ajax` call should probably go within the #submit click event listener.

Comment: Your php isn't echoing an object with an `html` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you don't need the JSON datatype, just return html.

Additionally, you'll want the ajax request to be inside the click event. In your click event, you also forgot to pass the `e` parameter.

```
$domain = $_POST['domain'];
$whois = new Whois();
header("content-type:text/html");
$res = $whois->getWhois($domain); // Calls the Whois-query function;

echo $res;
```

js:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var domain = $('#value').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/whois.php',
        type: "post",
        data: {'domain': domain, 'action': 'whois'},
        //dataType: "json",
        success: function(html) {
            $('#whoisResult').html('<h2>Whois Query result for ' + domain + '</h2>');
            $('#whoisContent').html(html);
        },

        error: function(xhr, status) {
            $('#whoisResult').html('<h2>Sorry, an error occured. Try again later, please!</h2>')
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I can see it returns me an HTML with correct WHOIS result, but it does not display it inside my div...

Comment: Does the first line get inserted? *"Whois Query Result for domain"*

Comment: Yes, it does. And this line is the only one

Comment: What does `console.log(html)` give you? (use a pastebin/similar or added it to your question)

Comment: It gives all WHOIS info, as well as I can see it in the response headers.

Comment: I'm interested in the html structure. Is it valid html? If you append `"Hello World!"` instead` of `html` do you see "Hello World!"?

Comment: It gives absolutely nothing, unfortunately. Even `Hello World`

Comment: Are you sure your div exists and is visible?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49973/discussion-between-artem-ushakov-and-kevin-b)